# Using the call function on MS-DOS to call all files in a directory with a certain extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, call

I have a code that calls specific files [.cmd files to be exact] using the call function, then echos a certain variable. This is highly inefficient due to the fact that the program needs to manually call each file. The current code, in case you need it is:

```
call afile.cmd
echo %Title%
call bfile.cmd
echo %Title%
pause > nul
```

[this is only the call part] Is there anyway to make it so it automatically calls all files with a .cmd extension, and displays all the %Title% variables without multiple

```
echo %Title%
```

functions?
I've tried using:

```
call *.cmd 
call *.*
call *
```

just to see if those would work [since the * usually defines all files] but they didn't. Any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
For %%a in (*.cmd) do (
 call "%%a"
 echo !title!
)
pause
```

Comment: When done with

     ECHO OFF

I get ECHO is off [x2]
When done without ECHO OFF
It just spits out all the echos and makes it unreadable to the untrained eye, and does not display the %Title% variable. Any solutions?

Comment: That is what I tried, and receive the double "ECHO is off" error message.

Comment: Is the %title% Variable defined in your CMD files ?

Comment: Yes, it is set as
"set Title= title"
It worked fine when manually calling the CMD files and manually echoing %Title% for each one, it was just an inconvenience for plugin makers because then they'd have to modify the client to make plugins.